# Piezo electric transducer-Vibration to Electrical Energy

Tags: piezo

I need to convert Vibrations into electricl enerery. Is it possible to convert it with the use of single chips?

Comment: What frequency range? That's basically what a lot of cheaper microphones are, just a piezoelectric material that directly converts sound waves to physical compression and thus to electrical signals. You just to need to have a basic amplifier circuit to amplify the signal, depending on your application of course.

Comment: for the audio frequency range. and also i should sense only vibrations. because lot of other noises are also present near by the device.

Comment: A piezoelectric transducer converts sound/vibration into electricity. End of story as far as the question is written. Now, maybe you want to add more to your question to justify why chips are needed?

Comment: I need to provide these output electrical signal to another chip. So i need chip so that it is easier to use

Comment: If it's in the audio range then you should be fine with most piezo sensors, though because of their size they may not react well at lower frequencies. You'll have to look at their data sheets to see their response/resonance.
In terms of your supplying the output to a "chip"... what kind of chip? Does it take analog input or do you need to pass it through a ADC? What input voltages does this "chip" take?

Comment: I cant find piezo sensors. Can you help in finding them. yes.. the output is fed into ADC chip...

Comment: Digikey has a few listed on their site:
http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/vibration-sensors/1966393

Comment: yes.. i have gone through it.. but they are very large in dimensions, is it is possible to get in small dimension

Comment: How small are you wanting? There are a few in there that are an inch or under. You have to keep in mind though that when it comes to vibrations, the sensor scales with the frequency sensitivity. The sensor is sensing vibrations based on resonance, and the lower the frequency you go, the larger it has to be (inversely, higher frequency sensors can be smaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess to put all of my comments into an answer to be more organized.
That's basically what a lot of cheaper microphones are, just a piezoelectric material that directly converts sound waves to physical compression and thus to electrical signals. You just to need to have a basic amplifier circuit to amplify the signal, depending on your application of course. Some sensors can provide digital output, otherwise most are going to be analog based and will probably need to be passed through an ADC. The frequency sensitivity will vary and you have to keep in mind that the sensitivity is based on resonance. Thus, a lower frequency vibration sensor is generally going to be larger than a higher frequency sensor.
[Digikey and others](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/sensors-transducers/vibration-sensors/1966393) have a nice selection of vibration sensors.