# Is it possible to create a piezo power generator?

Tags: power-supply, piezo

Piezoelectric effect can be reversed. Hence suppose a crystal and a steel frame with a screw built in it. When putting pressure on the crystal via screwing, a tension should appear between both sides of the crystal. Can this be used to create a kind of endless capacitor, and are there effects that forbid this usage?

Comment: Piezo crystals are AC only. I don't know the material physics of it, but if you deform the crystal, the voltage initially builds up then fades away.

Comment: And the crystal has internal resistance, it is not perfectly efficient, plus there will be energy lost to heat in the mechanical flexing of the crystal.

Comment: Yes thanks, this is what I thought. Were it possible to combine repulsive Casimir effect https://www.google.com/amp/s/phys.org/news/2017-04-harness-mysterious-casimir-tiny-devices.amp with piezo to create a small AC generator via a loopback for example : the tiny repulsive force would induces a tension on the piezo which shall make an oscillation ?

Comment: @DKNguyen I'll take exception to the fading away bit. I've been bitten by bare ceramic for a hydrophone with a simple capacitance around 10 nF sitting on my desk for a couple months. I probably got hit by >200V which was a bit surprising when I picked it up.

Comment: A battery is a source of electric power consisting of one or more **electrochemical** cells https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery

Comment: Piezo crystals are not conductive. So no "current" can be used ?

Comment: `Piezoelectric effect can be reversed.` - that would then become using a signal to generate movement.

Comment: Ok. I forget to specify "DC current" as "battery".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Piezo electric transducer-Vibration to Electrical Energy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121282/piezo-electric-transducer-vibration-to-electrical-energy)

Answer (score 3):

Piezos can generate energy. This can be demonstrated with a simple experiment: wire a LED to it and tap on the piezo with your finger. The LED will flash.

They can be thought of as a capacitor that charges itself when flexed: mechanical stress creates a movement of charge from one electrode to the other. This is reversible, so flexing in the other direction will move the charge back in the other direction.

However then only generate charge when they're being flexed: once they stop moving, the charge will remain if it is not consumed, but they won't generate more. If you flex a piezo in one direction, charge and voltage will be generated, then disappear if the force is removed and the piezo returns to non-stressed state.

So, to make a pizeo generator, you need a source of vibration (repeated flexing). Then the piezo will output an AC voltage, that can be rectified and used. It's very low power, but it is used for energy harvesting, for low power circuits like sensors, in places where you wouldn't want a battery.

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible to create a piezoelectric generator, but you probably won't get much energy out of it. Piezoelectric generators are usually used to generate high voltage. They are used in spark ignition such as what one would find in a outdoor grill. They are also used in LCD computer monitors that had florescent tubes (the small ones) and also in ultrasonic power supplies to generate high voltage. In these applications they use a a piezoelectric crystal as a transformer to make a smaller voltage pulse into a higher voltage pulse with an efficiency of less than 80%, so you won't get endless energy because of the 20% loss (probably due to them converting summer of the energy to heat)